# There was an error while trying to load the gem 'activerecord-nulldb-adapter'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, gems

Обновил Rails до версии 5.1.1. При запуске проекта появилась ошибка:

```
/Users/Colibri/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.14.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:94:in `rescue in block (2 levels) in require': There was an error while trying to load the gem 'activerecord-nulldb-adapter'. (Bundler::GemRequireError)
Gem Load Error is: superclass mismatch for class Schema
Backtrace for gem load error is:
/Users/Colibri/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-nulldb-adapter-0.3.6/lib/nulldb/extensions.rb:37:in `<module:ActiveRecord>'
/Users/Colibri/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-nulldb-adapter-0.3.6/lib/nulldb/extensions.rb:34:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/Colibri/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-nulldb-adapter-0.3.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/nulldb_adapter.rb:10:in `require'
/Users/Colibri/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-nulldb-adapter-0.3.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/nulldb_adapter.rb:10:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/Colibri/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-nulldb-adapter-0.3.6/lib/nulldb/core.rb:3:in `require'
/Users/Colibri/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-nulldb-adapter-0.3.6/lib/nulldb/core.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/Colibri/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-nulldb-adapter-0.3.6/lib/nulldb.rb:1:in `require'
/Users/Colibri/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-nulldb-adapter-0.3.6/lib/nulldb.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/Colibri/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-nulldb-adapter-0.3.6/lib/activerecord-nulldb-adapter.rb:1:in `require'
/Users/Colibri/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-nulldb-adapter-0.3.6/lib/activerecord-nulldb-adapter.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/Colibri/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.14.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:91:in `require'
/Users/Colibri/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.14.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:91:in `block (2 levels) in require'
/Users/Colibri/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.14.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:86:in `each'
/Users/Colibri/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.14.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:86:in `block in require'
/Users/Colibri/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.14.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:75:in `each'
/Users/Colibri/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.14.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:75:in `require'
/Users/Colibri/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.14.6/lib/bundler.rb:107:in `require'
/Users/Colibri/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/Projects/Project1/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/Colibri/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.1/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:129:in `require'
/Users/Colibri/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.1/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:129:in `block in perform'
/Users/Colibri/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.1/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:126:in `tap'
/Users/Colibri/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.1/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:126:in `perform'
/Users/Colibri/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/thor-0.19.4/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
/Users/Colibri/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/thor-0.19.4/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126:in `invoke_command'
/Users/Colibri/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/thor-0.19.4/lib/thor.rb:369:in `dispatch'
/Users/Colibri/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.1/lib/rails/command/base.rb:63:in `perform'
/Users/Colibri/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.1/lib/rails/command.rb:44:in `invoke'
/Users/Colibri/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:16:in `<top (required)>'
bin/rails:9:in `require'
bin/rails:9:in `<main>'
Bundler Error Backtrace:
    from /Users/Colibri/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.14.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:90:in `block (2 levels) in require'
    from /Users/Colibri/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.14.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:86:in `each'
    from /Users/Colibri/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.14.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:86:in `block in require'
    from /Users/Colibri/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.14.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:75:in `each'
    from /Users/Colibri/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.14.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:75:in `require'
    from /Users/Colibri/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.14.6/lib/bundler.rb:107:in `require'
    from /Users/Colibri/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/Projects/Project1/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/Colibri/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.1/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:129:in `require'
    from /Users/Colibri/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.1/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:129:in `block in perform'
    from /Users/Colibri/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.1/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:126:in `tap'
    from /Users/Colibri/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.1/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:126:in `perform'
    from /Users/Colibri/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/thor-0.19.4/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
    from /Users/Colibri/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/thor-0.19.4/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126:in `invoke_command'
    from /Users/Colibri/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/thor-0.19.4/lib/thor.rb:369:in `dispatch'
    from /Users/Colibri/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.1/lib/rails/command/base.rb:63:in `perform'
    from /Users/Colibri/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.1/lib/rails/command.rb:44:in `invoke'
    from /Users/Colibri/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:16:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:9:in `require'
    from bin/rails:9:in `<main>'
```

Ругается как я понял на этот gem: https://rubygems.org/gems/activerecord-nulldb-adapter/

Как исправить ситуацию?

Answer (score 0):

Разработчику гема нужно еще немного времени для выпуска релиза.

А пока вы можете использовать временное решение:

```
gem 'activerecord-nulldb-adapter', github: 'nulldb/nulldb', branch: 'rails-5-1'
```